# DateTimeFormatter - dynamic pattern

Tags: java

I have a pattern which will be available in property file or db. It will have literal text sandwiched in between and the thing is that the whole formatting pattern can be reshuffled any time based on requirement change, ie:

```
pattern = "4pm on Wednesday";
pattern = "at 4pm on Wednesday";
pattern = "on Wednesday at 4pm";
```

So this pattern will be passed to the DateTimeFormatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
```

So now we have code that is decoupled and future proof, ain't it? Because the code doesn't have to know exactly where the each pattern part (ie EEE/a/HH:MM, etc) is located.

But to indicate literal text we need to use quote for, say, 'on' or 'at' which the person, who put it there in the db or property file, has to know and do it with caution without miss.

So if the guy forgets to put the quote then the code will break. So my question is, it is better to keep the pattern and keep the code unaware of the exact pattern? or is it better to couple the code with the pattern ie the code has to know exactly the position of each pattern part and each time the requirement dictates a change the developer has to change it in the code which will prevent breaking the code?

Comment: if the litteral text content and position varies depending on which pattern is used then there should be some kind of mapping between your litteral text and the various patterns => distinguishing between the patterns at least in some sort of map

Comment: It depends.  If the requirement will eventually be settled to a fixed pattern before implementation then include it within the code.  If the requirement can change after implementation, but will be changed infrequently and does not have to immediately take effect, then still include it in the code.  Users will have to wait until the next deploy.  If the requirement can change after implementation and must become effective immediately then keep it external so it can be easily updated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends! :p

If your try is to have very flexible pattern, maybe you could test the pattern at the moment it is stored. Or maybe you could have a default pattern in case of FormatException.